# Expression.Invoke in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The Entity Framework does not support the `Expression.Invoke` operator.  You receive the following exception when trying to use it:

> "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Has anyone got a workaround for this missing functionality? I would like to use the PredicateBuilder detailed [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.html) in an Entity Framework context.

**Edit 1** @marxidad - I like your suggestion, however it does baffle me somewhat. Can you give some further advice on your proposed solution?

**Edit 2** @marxidad - Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yeah, looks like Entity Framework doesn't support this, nor could i jerry-rig a way to get it to evaluate in a way that would work.

Comment: have a look at the [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) now support Entity Framework.

Sorry, guys, for not doing this earlier!

Comment: Yep- it works now. Just add AsExpandable() before your .Where<>() and your good to go.

Comment: When I add the AsExpandable(), I'm receiving "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'." in the VisitInvocation at the line LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)target;

Answer (score 0):

The Entity framework converts LINQ expressions into Entity Command trees and within that only its canonical functions are supported. You'd have to use the command trees with canonical functions to do something like PredicateBuilder.