# How can I conditionally apply a Linq operator?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

We're working on a Log Viewer. The use will have the option to filter by user, severity, etc. In the Sql days I'd add to the query string, but I want to do it with Linq. How can I conditionally add where-clauses?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

if you want to only filter if certain criteria is passed, do something like this

```
var logs = from log in context.Logs
           select log;

if (filterBySeverity)
    logs = logs.Where(p => p.Severity == severity);

if (filterByUser)
    logs = logs.Where(p => p.User == user);
```

Doing so this way will allow your Expression tree to be exactly what you want. That way the SQL created will be exactly what you need and nothing less.

Comment: Hi Do you have any suggestions for making the where clauses ORs instead of ANDs ..?

Comment: Yeah... it's a bit tough to do. The best I've seen is through the specification pattern and pulling the predicate into the specification and then calling specification.Or(someOtherSpecification). Basically you have to write your own expression tree a bit. Example code and explanation here: http://codeinsanity.com/archive/2008/08/13/implementing-repository-and-specification-patterns-using-linq.aspx

Comment: I have a stupid question, If these logs are being acquired from database, are we getting all the logs and then filtering them in memory ? If so then how can i pass the conditions to database

Comment: it's not filtering them in memory. it's building up a query and sending all the conditions in the database (at least for most linq-to-x providers)

Comment: getting this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @AliUmair I've had similar errors. LINQ doesn't understand array indexing. Pull your array element value into a local variable and use your variable in the query. Example: instead of:
 `var query = from x in context.Logs where x.User == myArray[0] select log;`
use:
 `var u = myArray[0];
 var query = from x in context.Logs where x.User == u select log;`

Answer (score 28):

If you need to filter base on a List / Array use the following:

```
    public List<Data> GetData(List<string> Numbers, List<string> Letters)
    {
        if (Numbers == null)
            Numbers = new List<string>();

        if (Letters == null)
            Letters = new List<string>();

        var q = from d in database.table
                where (Numbers.Count == 0 || Numbers.Contains(d.Number))
                where (Letters.Count == 0 || Letters.Contains(d.Letter))
                select new Data
                {
                    Number = d.Number,
                    Letter = d.Letter,
                };
        return q.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: This is by far the best and most correct answer. The conditional || only compares the first part and skips the second if the first part is true... nicely done!

Comment: This construct includes the 'or' part of the expression in the generated SQL query. The accepted answer will generate more efficient statements. Depending on the data provider's optimizations, of course. LINQ-to-SQL may have better optimization, but LINQ-to-Entities doesn't.

Answer (score 20):

I ended using an answer similar to Daren's, but with an IQueryable interface:

```
IQueryable<Log> matches = m_Locator.Logs;

// Users filter
if (usersFilter)
    matches = matches.Where(l => l.UserName == comboBoxUsers.Text);

 // Severity filter
 if (severityFilter)
     matches = matches.Where(l => l.Severity == comboBoxSeverity.Text);

 Logs = (from log in matches
         orderby log.EventTime descending
         select log).ToList();
```

That builds up the query before hitting the database. The command won't run until .ToList() at the end.

Answer (score 19):

I solved this with an extension method to allow LINQ to be conditionally enabled in the middle of a fluent expression. This removes the need to break up the expression with `if` statements.

`.If()` extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> If<TSource>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        bool condition,
        Func<IQueryable<TSource>, IQueryable<TSource>> branch)
    {
        return condition ? branch(source) : source;
    }
```

This allows you to do this:

```
return context.Logs
     .If(filterBySeverity, q => q.Where(p => p.Severity == severity))
     .If(filterByUser, q => q.Where(p => p.User == user))
     .ToList();
```

Here's also an `IEnumerable<T>` version which will handle most other LINQ expressions:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> If<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    bool condition,
    Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>> branch)
    {
        return condition ? branch(source) : source;
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

When it comes to conditional linq, I am very fond of the filters and pipes pattern.
http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvcstore-part-3/

Basically you create an extension method for each filter case that takes in the IQueryable and a parameter.

```
public static IQueryable<Type> HasID(this IQueryable<Type> query, long? id)
{
    return id.HasValue ? query.Where(o => i.ID.Equals(id.Value)) : query;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Doing this:

```
bool lastNameSearch = true/false; // depending if they want to search by last name,
```

having this in the `where` statement:

```
where (lastNameSearch && name.LastNameSearch == "smith")
```

means that when the final query is created, if `lastNameSearch` is `false` the query will completely omit any SQL for the last name search.

Comment: Depends on the data provider. LINQ-to-Entities doesn't optimize it that well.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use something like the PredicateBuilder discussed [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.html).
It allows you to write code like the following:

```
var newKids  = Product.ContainsInDescription ("BlackBerry", "iPhone");

var classics = Product.ContainsInDescription ("Nokia", "Ericsson")
                  .And (Product.IsSelling());

var query = from p in Data.Products.Where (newKids.Or (classics))
            select p;
```

Note that I've only got this to work with Linq 2 SQL. EntityFramework does not implement Expression.Invoke, which is required for this method to work. I have a question regarding this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524/expressioninvoke-in-entity-framework).

Comment: This is a great method for those using a Business Logic Layer on top of their repository along with a tool like AutoMapper to map between data transfer objects and Entity models. Using the predicate builder will allow you to dynamically modify your IQueryable before sending it to AutoMapper for flattening i.e. bringing the list into memory.

Note that it also supports Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can create and use this extension method

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool isToExecute, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    return isToExecute ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the prettiest thing but you can use a lambda expression and pass your conditions optionally. In TSQL I do a lot of the following to make parameters optional:

> WHERE Field = @FieldVar OR @FieldVar IS NULL

You could duplicate the same style with a the following lambda (an example of checking authentication):

> MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
>
> void RunQuery(string param1, string param2, int? param3){
>
> > Func checkUser = user =>
> >
> > > ((param1.Length > 0)? user.Param1 == param1 : 1 == 1) &&
> > >
> > > ((param2.Length > 0)? user.Param2 == param2 : 1 == 1) &&
> > >
> > > ((param3 != null)? user.Param3 == param3 : 1 == 1);
> >
> > User foundUser = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(checkUser);
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement recently and eventually found this in he MSDN.
[CSharp Samples for Visual Studio 2008](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpsamples)

The classes included in the DynamicQuery sample of the download allow you to create dynamic queries at runtime in the following format:

```
var query =
db.Customers.
Where("City = @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
OrderBy("CompanyName").
Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

Using this you can build a query string dynamically at runtime and pass it into the Where() method:

```
string dynamicQueryString = "City = \"London\" and Order.Count >= 10"; 
var q = from c in db.Customers.Where(queryString, null)
        orderby c.CompanyName
        select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use C#'s && operator:

```
var items = dc.Users.Where(l => l.Date == DateTime.Today && l.Severity == "Critical")
```

Edit: Ah, need to read more carefully. You wanted to know how to *conditionally* add additional clauses. In that case, I have no idea. :) What I'd probably do is just prepare several queries, and execute the right one, depending on what I ended up needing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external method:

```
var results =
    from rec in GetSomeRecs()
    where ConditionalCheck(rec)
    select rec;

...

bool ConditionalCheck( typeofRec input ) {
    ...
}
```

This would work, but can't be broken down into expression trees, which means Linq to SQL would run the check code against every record.

Alternatively:

```
var results =
    from rec in GetSomeRecs()
    where 
        (!filterBySeverity || rec.Severity == severity) &&
        (!filterByUser|| rec.User == user)
    select rec;
```

That might work in expression trees, meaning Linq to SQL would be optimised.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I thought was you could put the filter conditions into a generic list of Predicates:

```
    var list = new List<string> { "me", "you", "meyou", "mow" };

    var predicates = new List<Predicate<string>>();

    predicates.Add(i => i.Contains("me"));
    predicates.Add(i => i.EndsWith("w"));

    var results = new List<string>();

    foreach (var p in predicates)
        results.AddRange(from i in list where p.Invoke(i) select i);
```

That results in a list containing "me", "meyou", and "mow".

You could optimize that by doing the foreach with the predicates in a totally different function that ORs all the predicates.