# Best way of constructing dynamic sql queries in C#/.NET3.5?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, .net-3.5

A project I'm working on at the moment involves refactoring a C# Com Object which serves as a database access layer to some Sql 2005 databases.

The author of the existent code has built all the sql queries manually using a string and many if-statements to construct the fairly complex sql statement (~10 joins, >10 sub selects, ~15-25 where conditions and GroupBy's). The base table is always the same one, but the structure of joins, conditions and groupings depend on a set of parameters that are passed into my class/method.

Constructing the sql query like this does work but it obviously isn't a very elegant solution (and rather hard to read/understand and maintain as well)... I could just write a simple "querybuilder" myself but I am pretty sure that I am not the first one with this kind of problem, hence my questions:

- How do *you* construct your database queries?
- Does C# offer an easy way to dynamically build queries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used C# and Linq to do something similar to get log entries filtered on user input (see [Conditional Linq Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries)):

```
IQueryable<Log> matches = m_Locator.Logs;

// Users filter
if (usersFilter)
    matches = matches.Where(l => l.UserName == comboBoxUsers.Text);

 // Severity filter
 if (severityFilter)
     matches = matches.Where(l => l.Severity == comboBoxSeverity.Text);

 Logs = (from log in matches
         orderby log.EventTime descending
         select log).ToList();
```

Edit: The query isn't performed until .ToList() in the last statement.

Comment: How are a bunch of IF statements a dynamic query?

Comment: The IQueryable<Log> gets converted to SQL in the last line, where the query is actually run; all Where LINQ statements become one SQL WHERE clause.  This is the way I do highly variable SQL as well.  It's much cleaner than trying to write a stored proc to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless executiontime is really important, I would consider refactoring the business logic that (so often) tends to find its way down to the datalayer and into gazillion-long stored procs. In terms of maintainabillity, editabillity and appendabillity I always try to (as the C# programmer I am) lift code up to the businesslayer.

Trying to sort out someone elses 8000 line SQL Script is not my favorite task.

:)

//W

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ](http://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+LINQ+tutorial) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'd do it:

```
public IQueryable<ClientEntity> GetClients(Expression<Func<ClientModel, bool>> criteria)
    {
        return (
            from model in Context.Client.AsExpandable()
            where criteria.Invoke(model)
            select new Ibfx.AppServer.Imsdb.Entities.Client.ClientEntity()
            {
                Id = model.Id,
                ClientNumber = model.ClientNumber,
                NameFirst = model.NameFirst,
                //more propertie here

            }
        );
    }
```

The *Expression* parameter you pass in will be the dynamic query you'll build with the different WHERE clauses, JOINS, etc. This Expression will get *Invoked* at run time and give you what you need.

Here's a sample of how to call it:

```
public IQueryable<ClientEntity> GetClientsWithWebAccountId(int webAccountId)
    {
        var criteria = PredicateBuilder.True<ClientModel>();
        criteria = criteria.And(c => c.ClientWebAccount.WebAccountId.Equals(webAccountId));
        return GetClients(criteria);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its worth considering if you can implement as a parameterised strored procedure and optimise it in the database rather than dynamically generating the SQL via LINQ or an ORM at runtime. Often this will perform better. I know its a bit old fashioned but sometimes its the most effective approach.

Comment: Yes, we have looked into that already but it doesn't really work as our queries change to much...

Answer (score 1):

I understand the potential of Linq but I have yet to see anyone try and do a Linq query of the complexity that Ben is suggesting

> the fairly complex sql statement (~10 joins, >10 sub selects, ~15-25 where conditions and GroupBy's)

Does anyone have examples of large Linq queries, and any commentary on their manageability?

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL together with System.Linq.Dynamic brings some nice possibilities.

I have posted a couple of sample code snippets here:
http://blog.huagati.com/res/index.php/2008/06/23/application-architecture-part-2-data-access-layer-dynamic-linq

...and here:
http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/6330927813/m/717004553931?r=777003863931#777003863931

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming at this late and have no chance for an upvote, but there's a great solution that I haven't seen considered:  A combination of procedure/function with linq-to-object.  Or to-xml or to-datatable I suppose.

I've been this in this exact situation, with a massive dynamically built query that was kindof an impressive achievement, but the complexity of which made for an upkeep nightmare.  I had so many green comments to help the poor sap who had to come along later and understand it.  I was in classic asp so I had few alternatives.

What I have done since is a combination of **function/procedure and linq**.  Often the *total complexity* is less than the complexity of trying to do it one place.  Pass some of the your criteria to the UDF, which becomes much more manageable.  This gives you a manageable and understandable result-set.  Apply your remaining distinctions using linq.

You can use the advantages of both:

- Reduce the total records as much as
  possible on the server; get as many
  crazy joins taken care of on the
  server.  Databases are *good* at this
  stuff.
- Linq (to object etc.) isn't as powerful but is great at expressing complex criteria; so use it for various possible distinctions that add complexity to the code but that the db wouldn't be much better at handling.  Operating on a reduced, normalized result set, linq can express complixity without much performance penalty.

How to decide which criteria to handle in the db and which with linq?  Use your judgement.  If you can efficiently handle complex db queries, you can handle this.  Part art, part science.

Comment: What you are saying is let the DB do what it's good at?  I think the linq KristoferA gets done is very impressive.  On the other hand, I am happier controlling the performance of the database with some transact SQL.

Note the abstraction layer for the database can be a set of classes.  The linq approach seems to be one of generic programming, but in reality you are then requiring the linq framework to manage queries in an optimal way.

So while technically impressive, it seems a little opaque if nothing else, and my prod environments put this stuff in stored procs anyway.

Comment: @polyglot  Yes, there are a huge amount of factors here, and all of us would give more focused advice if we had more specifics.  For a complicated search engine, I'm making a **good guess** based on my experience that it's all *performance* and *maintainability*.  The use of dynamics in KristoferA's examples may have a performance penality that outweighs its flexibility.  Linq to generic enumerables provides simplicity at an acceptable cost, as long as some heavy lifting is already done.  And with massively complex logic, I don't trust Linq-to-sql to set up the db-work efficiently.  Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider LINQ or an O/R Mapper like this one: http://www.llblgen.com/

Answer (score 0):

If using C# and .NET  3.5, with the addition of MS SQL Server  then LINQ to SQL is definitely the way to go.  If you are using anything other than that combination, I'd recommend an ORM route, such as [nHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate) or [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There a kind of experimental try at a QueryBuilder class at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sql-querybuilder-class. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://sqlom.sourceforge.net. I think it does exactly what you are looking for.