# Compare date in stored procedure in an exec statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
create stored procedure aaa 
     @columnName nvarchar(10), 
     @comparisonParam nvarchar(10),
     @val nvarchar(100) 
as
    declare @date date
    set @date = convert(@val, date)

    exec('select * from Sheep where ' + @columnName + @comparisonParam  + @date )
```

When actually the query is supposed to be like this:

```
select * from Sheep where birth_date = 12-12-2000
```

When I run the procedure it doesn't work with date value, but with string and int it works.

Answer (score 1):

The date value must be quoted.

On a side note, I'd warn against doing this. If you need to build up dynamic sql you need to consider the risks such as: sql injection attacks, bad syntax, invalid semantics etc.

Consider using an existing component to build the query. A few examples:

.NET LINQ (to SQL/Entities) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx

.NET SqlCommandBuilder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx

See [Best way of constructing dynamic sql queries in C#/.NET3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987/best-way-of-constructing-dynamic-sql-queries-in-c-net3-5)

Answer (score 0):

Your date literal needs to be surrounded in single quotes (I use CHAR(39) usually since it is easier to read and doesn't require escaping). Otherwise you are saying:

```
WHERE birth_date = (12) - (12) - (2000)
```

Which resolves to:

```
WHERE birth_date = -2000
```

Which resolves to `DATEADD(DAY, -2000, '1900-01-01')` or:

```
WHERE birth_date = '1894-07-11'
```

This is probably not going to yield the results you want.

With typical SQL injection warnings in place of course, and assuming that `@columnName` is always a string or date/time column, here is how I would re-write your stored procedure (though I would probably try to avoid the dynamic SQL altogether if I could).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.aaa 
  @columnName       NVARCHAR(10), 
  @comparisonParam  NVARCHAR(10),
  @val              NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Sheep WHERE '
    + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + @comparisonParam + CHAR(39) 
    + REPLACE(@val, CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)) 
    + CHAR(39);

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

In order to thwart potential issues you may want to add validation for columns and data types, and ensure that the operation is one you expect. e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bbb
  @columnName       NVARCHAR(10), 
  @comparisonParam  NVARCHAR(10),
  @val              NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1);

  SELECT @delimiter = CASE 
    WHEN [system_type_id] IN 
      (104,48,52,56,127,59,60,62,106,108,122) THEN '' -- numeric
    WHEN [system_type_id] IN 
      (35,40,41,42,43,58,61,99,167,175,231,239) THEN CHAR(39) -- string
    END FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Sheep')
    AND name = @columnName;

  IF @delimiter IS NULL
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Column ''%s'' was not found or an unexpected data type.', 11, 1, 
      @columnName);
    RETURN;
  END

  IF @comparisonParam NOT IN (N'=', N'>=', N'<=', N'<', N'>', N'LIKE')
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Comparison param ''%s'' was not valid.', 11, 1, @comparisonParam);
    RETURN;
  END

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Sheep WHERE '
           + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' ' + @comparisonParam + ' ' 
           + @delimiter + REPLACE(@val, CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)) 
           + @delimiter;

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Now make sure you use an unambiguous date format for your string literals. `12-12-2000` is not a good choice. `20001212` is much better.

There are possibly some ways to do this without dynamic SQL - I gave a [very simplified answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703750/61305). This may be feasible depending on the data types, the number of potential columns, and the number of operations you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

Build your dynamic SQL using a typed date parameter. Use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) which allows to pass parameter definitions and parameter values to the embedded SQL:

```
create procedure aaa 
   @columnName nvarchar(10), 
   @comparisonParam nvarchar(10),
   @val nvarchar(100)
as
    declare @date date, @sql nvarchar(max);
    set @date = convert(@val, date);

    -- Note how @date is a *variable* in the generated SQL:
    set @sql =N'select * from Sheep where ' + 
            quotename(@columnName) + @comparisonParam  + N'@date';

    -- Use sp_executesql and define the type and value of the variable
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@date date', @date;
```

Comment: The reason I didn't use a parameter for the value is that I'm not convinced the column being specified is always going to be a date.

Comment: @aaron I haven't considered that, true. I wanted to show that there is a way to avoid locale issues completely, by going strong typed. Of course, the parameter type should match the column type for added sargability.

Comment: Locale can still be an issue if the date is passed in to @val as a string.

Comment: True, but that is beyond my control. The point is that one can build a type safe, locale agnostic, dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
create stored procedure aaa 
     @columnName nvarchar(10), 
     @comparisonParam nvarchar(10),
     @val nvarchar(100) 
as
    declare @date date
    set @date = convert(@val, date)

    exec('select * from Sheep where ' + @columnName + @comparisonParam  + @date )
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to create table valued function for this rather than creating a stored procedure.

You can use any table valued function like

```
SELECT * from dbo.CallMyFunction(parameter1, parameter2
```

eg.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Sales.ufn_SalesByStore (@storeid int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT P.ProductID, P.Name, SUM(SD.LineTotal) AS 'Total'
    FROM Production.Product AS P 
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SD ON SD.ProductID = P.ProductID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SH ON SH.SalesOrderID = SD.SalesOrderID
    JOIN Sales.Customer AS C ON SH.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
    WHERE C.StoreID = @storeid
    GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.Name
);
GO
```

See this for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

**EDIT**

Instead of using dynamic sql try giving a thought on

```
SELECT * FROM 
FROM    [dbo].[Person]
WHERE   ([PersonID] = @PersonID
         OR @AreaID IS NULL
        )
        AND (([Code] BETWEEN @Code AND CHAR(255))
             OR @Code IS NULL
            )
        AND (([Name] BETWEEN @Name AND CHAR(255))
             OR @Name IS NULL
            )
        AND (([Notes] BETWEEN @Notes AND CHAR(255))
             OR @Notes IS NULL
            )
```

Comment: guys' i have a problem' the procedure cuts of part of my column name' why is that??

Comment: @RahellyGelfanboim for a string column I have used `[Code] BETWEEN @Code AND CHAR(255))
             OR @Code IS NULL` for string filtering. Use `=` in place of `BETWEEN` i.e. `[Code] = @Code OR @Code IS NULL`