# Filter by criteriums in linq query

Tags: linq

I have for example table cars

```
table cars(
producer varchar(30),
model varchar(30),
price integer,
start datetime,
end datetime)
```

and I need to return data from table using criterions ( based on one criterion , or two or all of them ). Is there any way to dynamically create linq question (just one linq query, not to create for all combinations different linq queries)? I can use some default values and search always buy all but that decrease my performance when I need to search by one or none.

Comment: Just FWIW, the singular is "criterion" and the plural is "criteria". A "criterium" is a type of bicycle race (one that has multiple laps on a relatively short course).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin     Can you help now ?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example as to what kinda query you would want and what data should return?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional Linq Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

You can start with [Dynamic LINQ Where Extension](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/ce6155fe-096d-400b-a69d-be389fa4d911.aspx)  to get something up and running but it will need a few enhancements to deal with DateTimes.

I use the above in conjunction with a loop to deal with the multiple criteria:

```
var q = from c in db.Cars select c;

filters.ForEach (filter =>
{
   q = q.Where (filter.Field, filter.Value, filter.Comparison);
});
```