# Multiple where conditions in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional Linq Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries)

Using Entity Framework 4.0

I have a search condition like this

[image]

There are four fields that allow the users to filter their search. The conditions are all `AND`. The result has to omit the corresponding filter if the textbox value is `String.Empty` or the dropdownlist value is **All**. Could do this in a Stored Procedure but I am unable to mimic that at all in a Linq2SQL/ Entity Framework scenario.

My question is this, how to omit  IEnumerable.Where in the Linq according to some entered values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries

Comment: You want all the conditions including String.Empty| dropdownList.Value!=-1 conditions fit into linq query? 
If not, you can make this an external condition and then just fit the filtering conditions into linq query.

Comment: @mootinator: thanks i am currently doing something like that. ia that the only way out?

Comment: why is that a bad thing? I would prefer that over having crazy boolean operators all over the place.

Comment: @RPM1984: its not bad at all. was enquiring about better options actually :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can chain your where clauses. You just need an IQueryable datasource.

```
var filteredData = _repository.GetAll();
//If your data source is IEnumerable, just add .AsQueryable() to make it IQueryable

if(keyWordTextBox.Text!="")
    filteredData=filteredData.Where(m=>m.Keyword.Contains(keyWordTextBox.Text));

if(LocationDropDown.SelectedValue!="All")
    filteredData=filteredData.Where(m=>m.Location==LocationDropDown.SelectedValue));

... etc....
```

Because it is IQueryable, the data is not fetched until you bind it so it only pulls the data you need.

Comment: so does the multiple `.Where()` act as an AND between the where. So for example: `db.Where(x=>x.A==true).Where(x=>x.B==true)`  is the same as `db.Where(x=> x.A==true && x.B == true)`

Comment: When you chain Wheres', they always append as an AND.

Comment: How about performance? Does splitting conditions across multiple `where` clauses cause overhead?

Comment: No, because it is not actually parsed until the query is materialized.

Comment: Is there a way so that `OR` is used instead of `AND` if I use multiple where?

Comment: `Because it is IQueryable, the data is not fetched until you bind it so it only pulls the data you need.` This is a very important line that should be at the top of any tutorial that deals with EF queries!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that Location and Category are identified in your code by ids (id is the value attribute in the comboboxes items), you can do something similar to

```
function GetItems(string keyword, string consultant, int? locationId, int categoryId){

using(MyContextEntities context = new MyContextEntities()){
    return context.Items.Where(item => 
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword) || item.Text.Contains(keyword))
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consultant) || item.Consultant.Contains(consultant))
        && (!locationId.HasValue || item.Location.Id == locationId.Value)
        && (!categoryId.HasValue || item.Category.Id == categoryId.Value)
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). It will allow you to do something like this:

```
IQueryable<??> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<??>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    if(temp != String.Empty || temp != "All")
          predicate = predicate.And(e => e.???.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.??.Where (predicate);
}
```

**Note:**

[image: Note]

Answer (score 2):

The flexible way to do this is to build up the where clause separately.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) article shows you how to do that. It takes a bit of work to initially set it up. But its worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
var abc = from al in myEntity.a
                  where (field == string.Empty ? al.field == string.Empty : al.field == field)
                  select new { al.field1, al.field2, al.field3 };
```

Answer (score -2):

I think Skip While and Take While may help in your situation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336757#SkipWhileSimple