# How should I expose the total record count and IEnumable collection of paged records from my service layer method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, pagination, repository

I am using EF4 with code first and have a repository for persistence and a service layer that interacts with it.  I have a service layer method that calls a IQueryable method on my repository and returns a IEnumerable containing the entities.  I also need to return the total record count so I can calculate the paging links.

How should I return both the int and IEnumerable from my service method?

- Use a out parameter on the method for the total row count
- Create a separate class that includes the total row count as a property
- Move the paging LINQ query out of the service layer (expose the IQueryable from the repo on the service layer)
- Create a full separate method on the service layer that does a new query just for count.

All of these should work, but which one is the cleanest?

**UPDATE:**  Here is some clarification of the architecture.  If this is wrong, then please tell me better way (eg - do the paging in the presentation layer instead of service layer,etc)

**Repo layer:**

returns IQueryable of DbSet, abstracts the db access from the presentation layer

**Service layer:**

does a LINQ query on the IQueryable to filter and just get the page items as needed using skip and take and returns a IEnumerable (going to also set to List on return to avoid any DbContext lifetime issues)

**Presentation layer:**

Call the method on the Service layer (getPagedResults(filters, pageNumber, pageSize))

From the looks of it I will also need to add a separate method to get the total results.  Was hopeing to do this all in one call.

I would prefer not to bring back all the records to presentation and then page... seems inefficient.

Comment: If you're already returning `IEnumerable<T>` is there some specific reason you don't just use `.Count()` on the `IEnumerable`?  Are you just presenting the subset to the front end?  Shouldn't the front end be responsible for paging?

Comment: The IEnumerable you return, does it contain all the items? (same nr. of items as count would return)

Comment: @AllenG - I was doing the paging in the service layer itself, then returning a list to the UI/Codebehind consumer.  This way I can avoid any issues with my Dbcontext lifetime.   Also, then I wouldn't have to send all the records to front end, then do the paging.. would directly fetch the records I  need in the service layer query.

Comment: @Magnus - I was trying to avoid sending all the items... Just take the ones I need via a query against the IQueryable returned from the repo.

Comment: Updated question to add more info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public class Repository<TEntity>
{
   public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetCollection(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, 
      int pageSize, int pageIndex)
   {
      return YourDbSet.Where(filter).OrderBy(sortExpression).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize);
   }

   public int Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
   {
      return YourDbSet.Where(filter).Count();
   }
}
```

Then You can write an extension method to use both of these methods

```
public static Pagination<TEntity> GetPagination<TEntity>(this Repository<TEntity> repository, 
   Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, int pageSize, int pageIndex)
{
   var entities = repository.GetCollection(filter, pageSize, pageIndex);
   var count = repository.Count(filter);

   return new Pagination(entities, pageSize, pageIndex + 1, count);
}
```

This way you can reuse `GetCollection` and `Count` methods independently.
You can build the where condition dynamically. Take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401712/how-to-make-a-compound-or-clause-in-linq/6401902#6401902)

Comment: I am still learning, so trying to stick to concrete implementations until I get my head around generics.

Comment: @Developr since you are using IQueryable you are already using generics. the generic parameters are inferred by the complier. so you don't have to give them

Comment: here is a link to another question that shows my architecture... very simple and concrete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416506/which-types-should-my-entity-framework-repository-and-service-layer-methods-retur

Answer (score 1):

If the `Enumerable` you are returning contains all the items, I would do a `ToList()` on it before returning if from the function. (you can then do `Count` with no cost on it)
If the function is returning a sub set of the total (using `Skip` and `take`) I would add a seperate function to get the total count.