# PredicateBuilder cannot convert to IQueryable?

Tags: linq, iqueryable, predicate, predicatebuilder

i have a function:

```
private IEnumerable<Promotion> MatchesKeyword(IEnumerable<Promotion> list, String keyword)
{
   ...snip...
}
```

which right now performs a LINQ query:

```
private IEnumerable<Promotion> MatchesKeyword(IEnumerable<Promotion> list, String keyword)
{
   return list.Where(item => item.Name.ContainsText(keyword)
      || item.Description.ContainsText(keyword)
      ...snip...
   );
}
```

This code works well enough.

But [i need to convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401712/how-to-make-a-compound-or-clause-in-linq) to use a [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
private IEnumerable<Promotion> MatchesKeyword(IEnumerable<Promotion> list, String keyword)
{
   var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Promotion>();     

   predicate = predicate.Or(item => item.Name.ContainsText(keyword)
         || item.Description.ContainsText(keyword)
         ...snip...
   );

   return list.Where(predicate);
}
```

Which, strangely, doesn't compile. The failing line is:

```
return list.Where(predicate);
```

You can take your pick of the errors:

- Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
- 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments
- Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.Func'

What's the problem? `IEnumerable` goes in, `IEnumerable` comes out.

i'll be honest, i read [the page on `PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and i don't understand ***any*** of it.

---

A *hint* of *why* i need to change to `PredicateBuilder` is:

```
private IEnumerable<Promotion> MatchesKeyword(IEnumerable<Promotion> list, String keyword)
{
   var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Promotion>();     

   predicate = predicate.Or(item => item.Name.ContainsText(keyword)
         || item.Description.ContainsText(keyword)
         ...snip...
   );

   DateTime dt = TryStrToDate(keyword);
   if (dt)
       predicate = predicate.Or(item => item.PromotionDate == dt);

   return list.Where(predicate);
}
```

...not that i need a reason, problem, practical example, or research effort to ask a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PredicateBuilder needs an `IQueryable<T>` to do its magic. Just change the last line in your example to

```
return list.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can compile expession to Func<T, bool>

```
expression.Compile();
```

It is suitable for Linq Where parameters.