# How to work with Conditional Linq Query?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional Linq Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries)

We're working on a Log Viewer. The use will have the option to filter by user, severity, etc. In the Sql days I'd add to the query string, but I want to do it with Linq. How can I conditionally add where-clauses?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are working with `IEnumerable`, like this:

```
IEnumerable<LogMessage> logs = /* whatever your source is */
if(condition) {
    logs = logs.Where(log => log.Severity == Severity.Error); // or whatever
}
```

You can also do this multiple times. If your data source is `IQueryable` use that instead of `IEnumerable`.