# Updating LINQ to add more conditions

Tags: c#, linq

```
        var rows = File.ReadAllLines(tempPath).Skip(1).Select(c => 
                                          {
                                              string[] args = c.Split('\t');
                                              return new
                                              {
                                                  foo = args[3]
                                              };
                                          }).Distinct();
```

How Can I add a `where condition` so it only returns `foo` values that their value is not `"N/A"` and is not `string.empty`?

Comment: What have you tried to do, and what problems have you had with your attempts?  Clearly you already know what method you should be using and what you want it to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional Linq Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries)

Comment: @Servy I don't know how to fit in the where clause in this case. Syntax.

Comment: @DarrenKopp He's not adding a where clause conditionally.  He's adding it unconditionally.

Comment: @user1899082 Did you look up the documentation of the method along with some basic examples of its usage?  It's syntax will be pretty much identical to the operations you're *already* performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rows = File.ReadAllLines(tempPath).Skip(1)
                                      .Where(c =>
                                      {
                                           string[] args = c.Split('\t');
                                           return args[3] != "N/A";
                                      })
                                      .Select(c => 
                                      {
                                          string[] args = c.Split('\t');
                                          return new
                                          {
                                              foo = args[3]
                                          };
                                      }).Distinct();
```

Comment: needed a string.empty check too but yeah that's the solution. Tested it, worked. Thank you .

Comment: one side question: If I add more fields to the return new part, for exampe now it is only foo..so adding more fields there,...then how would Distinct work?

Comment: Distinct will not work on objects, since it compare object reference and not object values.  That's why in my solution I do Distinct on selected tokens and then create new objects

Comment: Distinct uses the overload of Equals() on whatever object you return. You'd need to define a new class for your results and override the Equals method to get Distinct working as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem properly.

First you select only lines that don't have third token as "N/A" or empty string.
Second you get all third tokens
Third you get distinct values of the result
Four you create your object from valid tokens.

This way Distinct will work, as you looking for

```
var rows = File.ReadAllLines(tempPath).Skip(1)  
    .Where(c =>
    {
        string[] args = c.Split('\t');
        return args[3] != "N/A" && args[3] != string.Empty();
    })
    .Select(c => c.Split('\t')[3])
    .Distinct()
    .Select(c => 
    {
        return new
        {
            foo = c
        };
    });
```