# Conditionals inside Where Clause of LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to fine-tune the results in the controller action with a few parameters coming from client.

I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries).

The problem is the logs variable returns no results even if all the parameters are not there (I expect it to return all the records). It works perfectly fine  I do

```
return View(db.Logs.ToList());
```

But my implementation of the answer by Darren Kopp doesn't return anything at all. My code:

```
Category cat;
DateTime startDate;
DateTime endDate;

var logs = from log in db.Logs
           select log;

if (Enum.TryParse<Category>(viewModel.Category, out cat))
    logs = logs.Where(l => l.LogCategory == cat);

if (DateTime.TryParse(viewModel.StartDate, out startDate))
    logs = logs.Where(l => l.TimeStamp >= startDate);

return View(logs.ToList());
```

I am using VS 2015 & this is MVC 5. What is causing the problem?

Comment: I guess you need to cast into the list just after the filtration, as in  "logs = logs.Where(l => l.LogCategory == cat).ToList();" instead of "logs = logs.Where(l => l.LogCategory == cat);"

Comment: @ShilpaSoni: No, absolutely not. The OP only needs to call `ToList` once, at the end, which is already there...

Comment: So have you debugged into the code to see what `Enum.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParse` are actually returning? It sounds like it shouldn't be calling `Where` at all, rather than the problem being with the `Where` call itself...

Comment: Can you check in debug what values in your variables when you chouse nothing (`cat`, `startDate`, `endDate`)? I suppose even you don't fill them they have default value that ruin you everything.

Comment: What is the SQL being generated?  Is LogCategory defined as an int in the DB?

Comment: @JonSkeet A pleasure to see your exquisite suggestion here (for a person who actually learnt a bit of C# from your videos :-). The code is actually correct but the only strange thing is .NET's conversion of empty string to date 0001-01-01. That way, the conversion succeeded but resultant query was nonsensical. I have added string.IsNullOrEmpty() to the condition and it is working perfectly fine. Enum.TryParse works neat by the way.