# Filter all tables on Context Level

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF code first approch. Here is my context file.

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact_phone> Contact_phones{ get; set; }
    }
```

I want to add filter on bases of date on my context file, so that when i get data for any table i get for that specific date range only.
Please suggest.

Comment: It is a lil bit weird. Where do you want to take that Date ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are not talking about the relative easy filtering of your Contacts or Contact_Phones, but instead want something context wide for all tables? See [interceptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)

Comment: @CodeNotFound like i want data from current year only so i set dates for this year only and on all points it gives me data from only this year where ever i access on the application level.

Comment: @SteveGreene yes i need it for all the tables

Comment: So you must look interceptors as @SteveGreene suggested.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Not getting what it says.

Comment: You could also use database views that wrap the date range logic, and map your entities to the views instead of the base tables.

Comment: @sstan I need it on my code view because i have to apply filter by user input.

Comment: There are a lot of options, some mentioned above. Try some code and report back what the issues are. Just start with simple [chained where clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries) and build from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

The library has a Query Filter which does exactly this scenario.

Under the hood, it uses interceptor (for EF6) as Steve Grene suggested.

Wiki: [EF+ Query Filter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-filter)

**Filter Global**

```
startDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
QueryFilterManager.Filter<Contacts>(q => q.Where(x => x.CreatedDate > startDate));

// SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE CreatedDate > '2015-01-01'
var context = ctx.Contacts.ToList();
```

**Filter By Instance**

```
startDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
var ctx = new MyContext();
ctx.Filter<Contacts>(q => q.Where(x => x.CreatedDate > startDate));

// SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE CreatedDate > '2015-01-01'
var context = ctx.Contacts.ToList();
```

Comment: hi, can you update to show how this is possible across all entities globally, for e.g. tenantID?