# How to use an Expression<Func<Model, bool>> in a Linq to EF where condition?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linqkit

There have already been some questions about this topic (for instance [Expression.Invoke in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524/expression-invoke-in-entity-framework)), however, I could not find an answer for my specific situation.
I would like to define a method like this:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> condition)
{
    return from p in ctx.Customers.AsExpandable()
        where condition.Compile()(p)
        select p;
}
```

The AsExpandable method is from LinqKit (as it was adviced in the thread mentioned before).
However, when I try to call my method like his:

```
var customers = GetCustomers(c => c.ID == 1);
```

It throws an InvalidCastException:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.
>   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use an expression tree, you need to pass the expression tree itself to the LINQ method:

```
return ctx.Customers.AsExpandable().Where(condition)
```

Comment: `AsExpandable` isn't needed here, since you're not using `Invoke`.

Comment: @DCShannon: Typo; fixed.