# Sharing a where clause between LINQ statements

Tags: linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I have several LINQ-to-Entities queries that hit the same two tables and have the same few conditions. What I'm trying to do is share the where clause between multiple queries. For example, say I have this:

```
from t0 in db.Table0
from t1 in db.Table1
from t2 in db.Table2
where t0.Field7 == 'something' 
    && t1.Field1 > t2.Field3 
    && t2.NavigationProperty(t => t.Field4 == t1.Field2).Any()
select t0
```

What I would like is to be able to say something like this:

```
Func<Table1, Table2, bool> specialCondition
    = (t1, t2) => t1.Field1 > t2.Field3 
        && t2.NavigationProperty(t => t.Field4 == t1.Field2).Any();

from t0 in db.Table0
from t1 in db.Table1
from t2 in db.Table2
where t0.Field7 == 'something' && specialCondition(t1, t2)
select t1
```

This generates the `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.` which makes sense. It can't parse the arbitrary .NET function/delegate code into something it can pass to the database.

Everything I've read on the internet says expression trees, however, can work just fine.  My problem is while I can declare it (it's pretty much the same syntax as the function), I don't know how to use it.

```
Expression<Func<Table1, Table2, bool>> specialCondition
    = (t1, t2) => t1.Field1 > t2.Field3 
        && t2.NavigationProperty(t => t.Field4 == t1.Field2).Any();
```

What do I do with this? How do I pass it to LINQ2EF?

**Update:** Working solution with LinqKit as recommended by @Mic, pulled from NuGet (note the `.AsExpandable()` and the `.Invoke` and the snipped imported LinqKit reference and namespace):

```
Expression<Func<Table1, Table2, bool>> specialCondition
    = (t1, t2) => t1.Field1 > t2.Field3 
        && t2.NavigationProperty(t => t.Field4 == t1.Field2).Any();

from t0 in db.Table0.AsExpandable()
from t1 in db.Table1
from t2 in db.Table2
where t0.Field7 == 'something' && specialCondition.Invoke(t1, t2)
select t1
```

Checking in LinqPad, both the first completely inlined version and the final LinqKit Expression version generate the same SQL and results. Thanks a lot to you all for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such constructions are not possible in native L2S/L2Entities provider. You must use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) library, which supports expression expanding.

Comment: Looks hopeful. I was apparently wrong about the above Expression instantiation being that easy. It compiles, but doesn't run in the context of EF. When I include LinqKit and add `.AsExpandable()` to the first table and add `specialCondition.Compile()(t1, t2)` I get `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.` which looks similar to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795986/how-to-use-an-expressionfuncmodel-bool-in-a-linq-to-ef-where-condition)

Comment: Oops, I still had `Compile` in there instead of `Invoke` which appears to work fine. Thanks a lot for the point in the right direction. I'll edit the question with the functional code.

Answer (score 1):

Create the delegate using a [`CompiledQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.aspx).  I'm pretty sure it works in LINQ to Entities.  You just need to include the `DataContext` type as the first parameter.

```
Func<MyDataContext, Table1, Table2, bool> specialCondition =
    CompiledQuery.Create(
        (MyDataContext dc, Table1 t1, Table2 t2) =>
            t1.Field1 > t2.Field3
         && t2.NavigationProperty(t => t.Field4 == t1.Field2).Any());
```

Then to use it, you should be able to do this:

```
var query =
    from t0 in db.Table0
    from t1 in db.Table1
    from t2 in db.Table2
    where t0.Field7 == 'something' && specialCondition(db, t1, t2)
    select t1
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but upon further research, CompiledQuery isn't supported with DbContext in EF4.1 just yet, which is unfortunately what I'm using. It is a known limitation and they're working to get it added back in by the next release: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/02/ef-4-1-is-coming-dbcontext-api-amp-code-first-rtw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your LINQ query to LINQ expression syntax and pass your expression to `Where(expression)`.

Comment: All my LINQ queries are declarative (a syntax I find much easier to read) and not lambda. In trying to put together a short test, I find my problem is the expression has multiple inputs. If I had one table instead of two and I tacked a .Where() onto that one table, the expression does indeed work fine. My repeated condition is a relationship between several fields of more than one tables. Is there any way to pass more than one input to the expression?